# Which databases implement a difference between index scan and index seek?

Tags: sql-server, mysql, postgresql, oracle, index-tuning

Let's say I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE transactions (
    id NUMERIC(20, 0) PRIMARY_KEY,
    account_id VARCHAR(512),
    ...
    transaction_date TIMESTAMP
);
```

So with SQL Server, an index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX my_index ON transactions (account_id, transaction_date, id);
```

and a query:

```
SELECT id FROM transactions 
WHERE account_id = '123' 
AND transaction_date > '2023-01-01'
```

performs an Index Seek, meaning that the query is fulfilled from the index, not making a reference to the table, because all the data it needs is present on the table. If my index were:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX my_index ON transactions (account_id, transaction_date);
```

query would go to the table to fulfill the query (Index Scan). Which of the following databases:

1. Oracle
2. MySQL
3. PostgreSQL

support the above behavior?

Comment: All of these are available on https://dbfiddle.uk/ so you can test there and look at the explain plans. I would assume all of them support seeks and [Index-Only Scans](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-only-scan-covering-index)

Comment: Postgres does some weird stuff involving locking that means it always needs a Key Lookup back to the main table even after using an index.

Comment: @Charlieface - The "Index-Only Scan" link above says Postgres supports them since  release 9.2.

Comment: "*query would go to the table to fulfill the query (Index Scan)*" - FWIW, this doesn't have to be an index scan, and likely would invoke a Key Lookup operation instead (in addition to the original Index Seek).

Comment: @MartinSmith See the full docs https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html paragraph beginning "If these two fundamental requirements are met". Because it always uses Snapshot isolation, it looks up a visibility map, if that fails it forces a key lookup.

Comment: @J.D. I definitely had some terminology confusion. As far as I understand, every major DB supports this.

Comment: @HasanCanSaral Yes, this is a pretty fundamental function of indexes (seeking and scanning). So any relational database system should support this behavior.

Comment: You confuse the terms and their meaning. "Index seek" and "index scan" (which are in the question title) are SQL Server-specific terms, and they don't have much to do with the concepts of "covering index" or "index-only access" (which are in the question body). So, what is it that you want to know, exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is available with most major database vendors:

- [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/tuning/ctunoptimz30768.html)
- [MySQL](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-only-scan-covering-index)
- [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html)

Comment: Please post segment of supporting document.

Answer (score 1):

For *that* query and *that* composite index, MySQL will "seek" to ['123', '2023-01-01'], then "scan" until >123.

And, because the `PRIMARY KEY` is implicitly part of any secondary key,

```
 INDEX(account_id, transaction_date)
```

will have `id` on the end.  Hence, *that* query will be performed entirely in the INDEX's BTree.

Note that some other vendors do not include the PK; hence cannot perform the query query entirely in the 2-column index.

That is, in MySQL, these are equivalent, at least for the query in question:

```
 INDEX(account_id, transaction_date)
 INDEX(account_id, transaction_date, id)
```

(MySQL does not have the `NONCLUSTERED` keyword -- The PK *is* clustered; all other indexes are non-clustered.)